# Cannot access Jenkins on windows server EC2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance with Jenkins setup as windows service. I can see jenkins is up and running when I browse to     localhost:8080     on the EC2 instance but cannot access it from outside or its ip (using x.x.x.x:8080).

I have opened the 8080 port in firewall and tried to set the httpListenAddress in jenkins.config explicitly to 0.0.0.0 but no luck. It is funny though when I try the x.x.x.x I can see the default IIS page showing up.

I cant think of anything now. Anyone out there with a clue?

UPDATE:
@EEAA that was it! instance's security group! I was opening the port in the windows itself and forgot about the whole security group thing in aws console.
if you can post your comment I'll mark it as answer. thx

Comment: Did you open up tcp port 8080 in this instance's security group?

Comment: Wait, what? You see an IIS response on port 8080? Does that also happen when jenkins is not running? (That would be a pretty heavy clue if that were the case.)